# Laravel Cannot update or delete a parent row a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

[image]i am trying to run command php artisan migrate:rollback and it throw me the error cannot update or delete a parent row foreign key constraint fails

there is now issue when i run command php artisan migrate it successfully migrate my all tables but when i run rollback command it throw me the error the error is on my purpose_of_visits migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('purpose_of_visits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('purpose', 100);
        $table->string('description', 197);
        $table->integer('speciality_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->foreign('speciality_id')->references('id')->on('specialities')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('purpose_of_visits');
}
```

and my specialities migration:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('specialities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('description',250)->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->integer('created_by')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('updated_by')->unsigned()->nullable();

        $table->foreign('created_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('updated_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('specialities');
}
```

i cant figure out where is the issue even i am using onDelete('cascade')
your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: do you have down() schema?

Comment: yes i have down schema

Comment: can you edit your post and include the down() schema

Comment: i edit please review again

Comment: on roll back you have to delete  specialities table first .. migration is only happen the way its created or added

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have speciality_id, created_by and updated_by in the fillable property of your purpose_of_visits model. [See docs here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment).

For example on your model.

```
protected $fillable = ['speciality_id','created_by','updated_by'];
```

Comment: i have speciality_id in my fillable array

Answer (score 0):

Remove the foreign key constraints of the table before dropping it.

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('purpose_of_visits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['speciality_id']);
        $table->dropForeign(['created_by']);
        $table->dropForeign(['updated_by']);
    });
    Schema::dropIfExists('purpose_of_visits');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry For the Late reply There are Two Situation Where this error can be thrown

For Eg:
I have tables such as `posts, authors`

And here is my `post` table Migration

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->unsignedInteger('author_id');
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

and here is my `authors` table migration

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateAuthorsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('authors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('authors');
    }
}

Situation 1:
```

now if the `posts` table migration runs before the `authors` table migration it my throw the error

Situation 2:

in some cases if you miss `unsigned`  it may throw error

```
Solution1:
```

use

```
$table->unsignedInteger('speciality_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('speciality_id');
                $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('specialities')->onDelete('cascade');
```

instead of this

```
$table->integer('speciality_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('speciality_id')->references('id')->on('specialities')->onDelete('cascade');
```

if it again fails use this

```
try composer dumpautoload
```

adn then
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

At the beggining of the migration

and at the end

Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();

eg: you migration may look like

```
public function up()
    {
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
```

**and if the same error throws please attach Error Screenshot and commet below**

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi issue is same please see the attach screenshot of the eror

Comment: i have attach the screen shot please review or if u say i can we come on chat?

Comment: can you please share the url of the image

Comment: please provide the full image with the migration file name in commad line